# Voting buttons, Yes and No. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit, voting

Hi I'm adding voting to my site. Users can vote Yes or No. I made the form but it returns an error, only for the Yes button

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.votes.build]) do |c| %>
            <%= c.input value: 1, type: :hidden %>
            <%= c.submit :Yes, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

This is error: **We're sorry, but something went wrong.**

In theory I want to make something like this form:

```
<div class="text-success">
    Votează inițiativa<br>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary">PRO</button> sau 
    <button class="btn btn-danger">CONTRA</button>
</div>
```

See my controller:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @votes = @post.votes.create(votes_params)
        @votes.user = current_user
        @votes.save
    redirect_to @votes
  end

    private

    def votes_params
        votes_params = params.require(:votes).permit(:stare)
    end
end
```

See my model:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :post
end
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post your actual error -- generally by typing `heroku logs` (sounds like you've got it running in production)

From what I can see, I'd try fixing the error like this:

```
 <%= form_for([@post, @post.votes.build]) do |c| %>
      <%= c.input value: 1, type: :hidden %>
      <%= c.submit :Yes, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>


  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @votes = @post.votes.create(votes_params)
        @votes.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private

  def votes_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:stare).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

I think your `params hash` will be somewhat malformed - you'd need to post it to help us appreciate how to fix the error properly

Comment: I tried your code, but recived error is the same. When i type in console _heroku logs_ i recive this:
! No app specified.!    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.

Comment: Are you hosting with Heroku or another platform?

Comment: Mmmm... I solved this problem. It is Development mode, not production... Don't now why i get so non-informationaly errors. It's sad. The problem was with my model.

Thanks anyway.